# Unable to import module 'app': No module named '_tkinter'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"

Tags: python, docker, tkinter, aws-lambda, pytorch

I am trying to create a docker container to deploy on AWS lambda but I continuously keep getting the error:

```
"Unable to import module 'app': No module named '_tkinter'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}
```

The docker file I have created is as below:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install gcc
RUN yum install -y gcc-c++
RUN yum install -y git
RUN yum install -y which
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && pip install -e git+https://github.com/ganesh3/icevision.git@master#egg=icevision[inference] --upgrade -q
COPY model_dir ./model_dir
COPY /app/app.py   ./
CMD ["app.handler"]
```

The requirements.txt is as below:

```
--find-links  https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.10.0+cpu 
torchvision==0.11.1+cpu
--find-links  https://download.openmmlab.com/mmcv/dist/cpu/torch1.10.0/index.html
mmcv-full==1.3.17
mmdet==2.17.0
numpy
Pillow
tk
```

The app.py is as below:

```
# app.py used in the early stages of the project just to test if I was able to import the icevision library
import sys
import os
print("Executing install for fonts")
os.system('mkdir -p /root/.icevision/fonts/')
os.system('curl -LJO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/airctic/storage/master/SpaceGrotesk-Medium.ttf')
os.system('cp SpaceGrotesk-Medium.ttf /root/.icevision/fonts/')
os.system('yum install -y tkinter tcl-devel tk-devel')
os.system('yum search tkinter')
os.system('yum install -y python3-tkinter.x86_64')
print("Before tkinter import")
import tkinter
print("After tkinter import")
import icevision
def handler(event, context): 
    return 'Hello from AWS Lambda using Python ' + sys.version + ' and IceVision ' + icevision.__version__ + '!'
```

I also logged into the docker container using:

```
docker exec -it <container_name> sh
```

Then I logged into the python shell and ran:

```
>>> import icevision
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/task/src/icevision/icevision/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from icevision import parsers
  File "/var/task/src/icevision/icevision/parsers/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from icevision.parsers.parser import *
  File "/var/task/src/icevision/icevision/parsers/parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from icevision.data import *
  File "/var/task/src/icevision/icevision/data/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from icevision.data.convert_records_to_coco_style import *
  File "/var/task/src/icevision/icevision/data/convert_records_to_coco_style.py", line 17, in <module>
    from icevision.models.inference import *
  File "/var/task/src/icevision/icevision/models/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from icevision.models import mmdet
  File "/var/task/src/icevision/icevision/models/mmdet/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from icevision.models.mmdet.models import *
  File "/var/task/src/icevision/icevision/models/mmdet/models/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from icevision.models.mmdet.models import mask_rcnn
  File "/var/task/src/icevision/icevision/models/mmdet/models/mask_rcnn/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from icevision.models.mmdet.common.mask.two_stage import *
  File "/var/task/src/icevision/icevision/models/mmdet/common/mask/two_stage/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from icevision.models.mmdet.common.mask.two_stage.model import *
  File "/var/task/src/icevision/icevision/models/mmdet/common/mask/two_stage/model.py", line 3, in <module>
    from turtle import back
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I ran the following in the python shell:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', 'tk'])
```

I also ran the following to install tkinter:

```
yum install -y tkinter
yum install -y python3-tkinter
```

The import for tkinter still fails. I am checking this as I am getting this error irrespective of importing tkinter or not as some other library is importing it internally.

Can someone please suggest changes to resolve the error?

Warm Regards
Ganesh Bhat

Comment: Can you run those `yum` commands just once in the Dockerfile, rather than repeating them every time the program runs?  It's possible that will resolve the loading issue as well.

Comment: I ran all of them in the Dockerfile first and since it did not resolve it, I tried bring it into the app.py to check if there is a python package issue which was not the case as the package was installed but import tkinter is not able to find the package.

Answer (score 0):

Commented out the below code to resolve the issue:

```
from turtle import back
```